# Generic List and static variable behaviour in c#

Tags: c#

I have a simple application in C#. When I ran the code I am not getting the expected result?.I am getting 2,2,1 but i was expecting 1,2,3

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyList<int> list1 = new MyList<int>();
            MyList<int> list2 = new MyList<int>();
            MyList<double> list3 = new MyList<double>();
            Console.WriteLine(list1.GetCount());
            Console.WriteLine(list2.GetCount());
            Console.WriteLine(list3.GetCount());
        }
    }
    public class MyList<T>
    {
        static int _count;
        public MyList()
        {
            _count++;
        }
        public int GetCount()
        {
            return _count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: What result did you expect? I would think it would write the number 3... all 3 times.

Comment: @Joel &  Albin:I am getting 2,2,1 but from the code it is clear that i am creating three instance of the class so that constructor will be called three times.

Comment: @santosh - Actually that makes sense. You have only created 2 MyList<int> and 1 MyList<double>.

Comment: I guess he's expecting "2 2 1"...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The result is as I expect

```
2
2
1
```

This [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gusperez/archive/2005/08/09/449363.aspx) tells

> A static variable in a generic class declaration is shared amongst all instances of the same closed constructed type (§26.5.2), but is not shared amongst instances of different closed constructed types. These rules apply regardless of whether the type of the static variable involves any type parameters or not.

Answer (score 7):

The reason this works this way has to do with how many values are generated for a single static declaration.  There will be one static value per type in a given `AppDomain`.

In the non-generic case this means there is a 1-1 relationship between declaration and values.  After all there is only one `string` type in a given `AppDomain`.

In the generic case though it's a bit more involved.  The types `MyList<int>` and `MyList<double>` are actually different types.  Hence they have separate static values which are independent of each other.

Comment: Nope, the generic parameter makes it `2,2,1`.

Comment: @Doggett: That would explain it :)

Comment: @Jon, @Albin, @Dogget, changed my answer to reflect the new question.  Really wish we would get status notifications when a question is editt'd by the OP for which we have an answer.

Comment: im more of a java man than a c # man, but could you change this behavior by changing its declared scope? (does c# default to private or protected?) Also would this behavior hold true if the count happened in a superclass? i.e. MyList<generic> extends OurList <- which has the constructor counter. Will .net still recognize the two as in different namespaces from the same superclass above the generic handler?

Answer (score 2):

Changed my answer to reflect your generic question, you could do something like this, don't think there's a nice way around having to define a type for the static counter.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyList<int> list1 = new MyList<int>();
            MyList<int> list2 = new MyList<int>();
            MyList<double> list3 = new MyList<double>();
            Console.WriteLine(list1.GetCount());
            Console.WriteLine(list2.GetCount());
            Console.WriteLine(list3.GetCount());
        }
    }

    public class MyList<T>
    {
        private static int _count;
        private int _myCount;

        public MyList()
        {
            _myCount = ++MyList<object>._count;

        }
        public int GetCount()
        {
            return _myCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are expecting 1, 2, 3? If so, you need to make a modification:

```
public class MyList
{
    static int _count;
    private int myCount;

    public MyList()
    {
        this.myCount = ++_count;
    }
    public int GetCount()
    {
        return this.myCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you're expecting to see

1
2
3

but you're getting

3
3
3
instead.

The following will give you 1 2 3:

```
        MyList list1 = new MyList();
        Console.WriteLine(list1.GetCount());
        MyList list2 = new MyList();
        Console.WriteLine(list2.GetCount());
        MyList list3 = new MyList();
        Console.WriteLine(list3.GetCount());
```

Answer (score 1):

Each `MyList<T>` object is completely separate within the `AppDomain` based on the type of T. So in your case, you have 2 `MyList<int>` objects and 1 `MyList<double>` object. Since there is no actual connection between these objects in the typing system, the other solutions for adding an additional private counter will not work. Your counter will have to be external.

Answer (score 1):

`MyList<int>` and `MyList<double>` are compiled into strict but seperate types, which means when you call the constructors you are incrementing the static count of `MyList<int>` twice, and then the static count of `MyList<double>` once, hence 2, 2, 1.

Comment: Yes, but you are instantiating `MyList<int>` twice, and `MyList<double>` once. Two seperate types, two static fields.

Answer (score 0):

The result should be

```
3
3
3
```

What were you expecting?

Comment: I suspect he was expecting "1 2 3"

Comment: Nope, the generic parameter makes it `2,2,1`.