# Does C# generate concrete implementation for unused template parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, static

If I have

```
abstract class Base<TSub>
{
    protected static List<TSub> MyStaticList;
}

class DerivedA : Base<DerivedA>
{
}

class DerivedB : Base<DerivedB>
{

}
```

I get two independent MyStaticList variables, one for each base class.
If instead the base looked like this

```
class Base<TSub>
{
    protected static List<string> MyStaticList;
}
```

i.e., the template parameter was nowhere used, am I guaranteed to still get two independent MyStaticList variables?

(I need this for the `availableValues()` method of a customized Enum-like class hierarchy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gusperez/archive/2005/08/09/449363.aspx

> A static variable in a generic class declaration is shared amongst all
>   instances of the same closed constructed type (§26.5.2), but is not
>   shared amongst instances of different closed constructed types. These
>   rules apply regardless of whether the type of the static variable
>   involves any type parameters or not.

**EDIT**
A very similar question was asked before [Generic List and static variable behaviour in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327332/generic-list-and-static-variable-behaviour-in-c-sharp)

You'll have to go with a fully static construct to use inside of your generic classes. Maybe something like...

```
protected static List<TSub> MyStaticList = BaseUtil.MyStaticList
```

Comment: even if the type parameter is not used *at all*? So I could use an "unused" type parameter just to force a separate MyStaticList to be created?

Comment: @B3ret Absolutely, you can. Even if the type is not used, you get a different class incompatible with the one created using a different set of type parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Two instantiations of a generic class with different type parameters will result in two independent classes, each with its own set of static variables. So the answer is yes, the static variables `Base<ClassA>.MyStaticList` and `Base<ClassB>.MyStaticList` will be independent.

If you would like an opposite behavior (i.e. all generic classes sharing the same static variable) move the variable declaration into a non-generic class, and make it the base class of your generic, like this:

```
public class BaseOfGeneric {
    protected static List<string> MyStaticList;
}
abstract class Base<TSub> : BaseOfGeneric 
{
    ...
}
```

Now all instances of `Base<T>` will share the same `MyStaticList`, regardless of their type parameters.